# Find Tab at beginning of string and replace

Tags: regex

I am using this to find ^\t+ a tab at the beginning of the string and replace it with a space, the issue is that if the string has more than one tab it wont replace it with multiple spaces. how can i replace the tab on the beginning with the same amount of spaces?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Try `\G\t`

Comment: i believe its perl

Comment: So you just have Regex without any programming language?

Comment: i have a find and replace app that uses Perl-style regular expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\G\t
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN5hE9/1)

The `\G` matches the start of string and the end  of the previous successful match and `\t` will match 1 tab. With multiple search mode enabled (global mode), you will replace each tab at the start of the string with a space.

If you deal with tabs at the beginning of a *line*, you may use

```
(?:^|\G)\t
```

This expression was tested and works well in Notepad++.

Comment: Coming back to the flavor - what is the environment? You say *app that uses Perl-style regular expressions* - see my demo, it is exactly for the PCRE flavor.

Comment: find and replace manual says "Our program supports Perl-style regular expressions."

Comment: JS also claims their regex is Perl-style. If the tool supports ECMAScript 5 regex, you are stuck *if* you do not have access to programming code. Are you working with *lines*, or just strings? Try also `(?:^|\G)\t` (it works in Notepad++).